# How to store the reference of value type in a list?

Tags: c#

How to store the reference of value type in a list?

In following code,

```
int x = 1;
list<int> l = new list<int>();
l.add(x);
x = 2;
l[0].toString();
```

I hope **l[0].toString()** will be **2**.
I've tried to solve using **ref**, but I can't do and find any solutions.

Comment: You can't do that with value types, even with reference types, you will see more of a side effect, not a real reference *(You can't set it to null)*. Why do you need something like that ? If you can be clear about your requirements, there might be something better.

Comment: Use a container like `StrongBox<T>`, ugly but might work.

Comment: "Reference of value type"... no.

Comment: The reason is that I want to treat some points in a instance. but point is **Vector**, a value type in unity.

Comment: I mean, I hope 'instance A' can handle any other instance(B, C, ...)'s position through a list.

Answer (score 1):

Use a wrapper class:

```
class ReferenceValue<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public ReferenceValue()
    {
    }

    public ReferenceValue(T value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator ReferenceValue<T>(T v)
    {
        return new ReferenceValue<T> { Value = v };
    }

    public static implicit operator T(ReferenceValue<T> r)
    {
        return r.Value;
    }

    // would be useful to override equality, == and comparison operators
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var val = this.Value;
        if (val != null)
        {
            return val.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
var list = new List<ReferenceValue<int>>(new ReferenceValue<int>[] { 1, 2, 3 });

var ref1 = list[0];
var ref2 = new ReferenceValue<int>(4);

list.Add(5);
list.Add(ref2);

list[3].Value = 4;
ref2.Value = 5;

ref1.Value = 0;

// Prints: 02345
foreach (var val in list)
{
    Console.Write(val.Value);
}
```

Comment: I would remove those implicit operators, at least the one for `T` to `ReferenceValue<T>`, else it might be non-obvious why it does not work ;p

Comment: @leppie, I removed my other comment.  Please excuse me, I'm running on low sleep.  Your point about the implicit conversion is well taken.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a value type, you can't treat it like a reference (class) type.  Your code above will not work because `int` is a value type.

You *could* create a `class` that held the int and store instances of that in the `List`, then change the value of the int through `get/set` accessors in the class.

Does that make sense?

Comment: @leppie - storing reference types in the list *will* do what he is trying to accomplish which is changing the value of the item after it has been added to the list.

Comment: After you edited your answer again, that will work :)

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of getting downvoted.. here's one way you might do what you want. I'm giving you the gun and hoping you don't shoot yourself.

Fun to throw together though;

```
unsafe {
    var x = stackalloc int[1];
    *x = 1;

    var list = new List<IntPtr>() { (IntPtr)x };

    (*x)++;

    Console.WriteLine(*((int*)list[0])); // prints "2"
}
```

Comment: 4 minutes in and no downvotes. I'm glad people have accepted that I gave the OP prior warning :)

Comment: Looks like someone noticed the unsafe keyword... Also, keeping a reference to the list beyond the scope of `x` would be rather problematic -  at which point, `x` can just be `int x = 1; new List<IntPtr> { (IntPtr)(&x) }; x++;`.

Comment: Win some ... lose some.. :)

Answer (score -2):

You also need to update the x in the list

```
int x = 1;
list<int> l = new list<int>();
l.add(x);
x = 2;
l[0] = x;
l[0].toString();
```

will return :

> 2

Comment: well yeah, but that's not the question

Comment: I just want to access to **x** through the list without updating.